# Xml query resulting in error in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

This is my xml query

```
declare @XML xml
set @XML=
'<ROOT>
<Customers>
<CustomerId>1111</CustomerId>
<CompanyName>Sean Chai</CompanyName>
<City>NY</City>
</Customers>
<Customers>
<CustomerId>1112</CustomerId>
<CompanyName>Tom Johnston</CompanyName>
<City>LA</City>
</Customers>
<Customers>
<CustomerId>1113</CustomerId>
<CompanyName>Institute of Art</CompanyName>
</Customers>
</ROOT>';

SELECT
R.Node('.').value('(/Customers/CustomerId/.)[1]','varchar(100)') AS CustomerID,
R.Node('.').value('(/Customers/CompanyName/.)[1]','varchar(100)') AS CompanyName
FROM @XML.nodes('/ROOT/Customers') R(Node)
```

But its giving error:

```
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Cannot find either column "R" or the user-defined function or aggregate "R.Node", or the name is ambiguous.
```

i searched but couldn't get `R.node` Thing pls somebody guide me onthis !

and i'm not understanding  `@XML.nodes('/ROOT/Customers') R(Node)` ?

what is its use in query!

Answer (score 1):

Change the query like this and try

```
SELECT
R.Node.value('(CustomerId/.)[1]','varchar(100)') AS CustomerID,
R.Node.value('(CompanyName/.)[1]','varchar(100)') AS CompanyName
FROM @XML.nodes('/ROOT/Customers')  R(Node)
```

First of all you have syntax error in your query. You have aliase to your resultant table as  R(Node), then you cannot specifiy the path as R.Node(.).
Secondly the path that you mentioned in your query is wrong (/Customers/CustomerId/.)

Comment: Wow! could you pls Explain what was the error or mistake in my query? or how this works.. thanks in advance

Comment: @user3449213, i have updated the answer with the problems in your query

Comment: thanks man! i changed your query to this `SELECT
R.Node.value('(CustomerId/.)[1]','varchar(100)') AS CustomerID,
R.Node.value('(CompanyName/.)[1]','varchar(100)') AS CompanyName,
R.Node.value('(City/.)[1]','varchar(100)') as CityName
FROM @XML.nodes('/ROOT/Customers')  R(Node)` !

Comment: could you please also tell me what does `[1]` mean in your query?

Comment: That is copied from your query in fact :). value() function expects to have a single node to convert it to the specific type. Since the xpath CompanyName/. can lead to multiple nodes, although we have only one, we need to tell to take the first one. so we need to mention [1]