# Insert data in to table using xml and stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

[image]

I am trying to insert data in to table while doing this is I am getting an
error

> Cannot find  column name or user define function "Tbl.Col.value" or aggregate Tbl.Col.value or the name is ambiguous

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Ecal_InsertVerniercal_Sp 
    @exml XML
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Vernier_Gauge_Calibration (Comment, Report_Number, Acceptance_Status, Calibration_Date, Approved_By)
        SELECT
            Tbl.Col.value('@Reamrk', 'varchar(200)') AS Reamrk,
            Tbl.Col.value('@ReportNo', 'nvarchar(255)') AS ReportNo,
            Tbl.Col.value('@Status', 'varchar(MAX)') AS Status,
            Tbl.Col.value('@CalDate', 'datetime') AS CalDate,
            Tbl.Col.value('@CalBy', 'datetime') AS CalBy
        FROM 
            @exml.nodes('/CalibrationData/CalInfo') AS Tbl (Col)

    RETURN;
END
GO
```

Here is my XML, it dynamically generated in jQuery.

```
<calibrationdata>
    <extreading>
        <er>
        </er>
    </extreading>

    <internalreading>
        <ir>
        </ir>
    </internalreading>

    <masterdata>
        <mb1>110118</mb1>
        <desc1>Vernier Caliper-Height-0-to-600</desc1>
        <duedt1>02/06/2016</duedt1>
        <rmk1>TL-14/VER-0154</rmk1>
        <mb2>
        </mb2>
        <desc2>
        </desc2>
        <duedt2>
        </duedt2>
        <rmk2>
        </rmk2>
        <mb3>
        </mb3>
        <desc3>
        </desc3>
        <duedt3>
        </duedt3>
        <rmk3>
        </rmk3>
        <mb4>
        </mb4>
        <desc4>
        </desc4>
        <duedt4>
        </duedt4>
        <rmk4>
        </rmk4>
        <mb5>
        </mb5>
        <desc5>
        </desc5>
        <duedt5>
        </duedt5>
        <rmk5>
        </rmk5>
        <mb6>
        </mb6>
        <desc6>
        </desc6>
        <duedt6>
        </duedt6>
        <rmk16>
        </rmk16>
    </masterdata>

    <calinfo>
        <reamrk>fdg</reamrk>
        <reportno>ALIL-2015-12-104-5</reportno>
        <status1>Accepted</status1>
        <caldate>31/12/2015</caldate>
        <calby>Alok Sahu</calby>
    </calinfo>

    <visualpara>
        <vp1>Clamp,,Lock,,Fine_Adjustment,,Rusty,,Damage,,Dent_Marks,,</vp1>
        <vp2>External_Jaws,,Shims,,Jaw_Movement,,</vp2>
    </visualpara>
</calibrationdata>
```

Comment: Can you share the sample format of your XML value `@exml`

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24527653/2451726) may give some idea to your question.

Comment: hi all i have added the xml in my question as I don't know how to share it here plz check it

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<calibrationdata>
    <extreading>
        <er></er>
    </extreading>
    <internalreading>
        <ir></ir>
    </internalreading>
    <masterdata>
        <mb1>110118</mb1>
        <desc1>Vernier Caliper-Height-0-to-600</desc1>
        <duedt1>02/06/2016</duedt1>
        <rmk1>TL-14/VER-0154</rmk1>
        <mb2></mb2>
        <desc2></desc2>
        <duedt2></duedt2>
        <rmk2></rmk2>
        <mb3></mb3>
        <desc3></desc3>
        <duedt3></duedt3>
        <rmk3></rmk3>
        <mb4></mb4>
        <desc4></desc4>
        <duedt4></duedt4>
        <rmk4></rmk4>
        <mb5></mb5>
        <desc5></desc5>
        <duedt5></duedt5>
        <rmk5></rmk5>
        <mb6></mb6>
        <desc6></desc6>
        <duedt6></duedt6>
        <rmk16></rmk16>
    </masterdata>
    <calinfo>
        <reamrk>fdg</reamrk>
        <reportno>ALIL-2015-12-104-5</reportno>
        <status1>Accepted</status1>
        <caldate>31/12/2015</caldate>
        <calby>Alok Sahu</calby>
    </calinfo>
    <visualpara>
        <vp1>Clamp,,Lock,,Fine_Adjustment,,Rusty,,Damage,,Dent_Marks,,</vp1>
        <vp2>External_Jaws,,Shims,,Jaw_Movement,,</vp2>
    </visualpara>
</calibrationdata>'


SELECT
        Tbl.col.value('reamrk[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS Reamrk ,
        Tbl.col.value('reportno[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') AS ReportNo,
        Tbl.col.value('status1[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') AS Status,
        convert(datetime,(Tbl.col.value('caldate[1]', 'varchar(50)')),103) AS CalDate,
        Tbl.col.value('calby[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS CalBy
    FROM @MyXML.nodes('calibrationdata/calinfo') AS Tbl (col)
```

Change `Tbl.col.value('caldate[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS CalDate,`
to `convert(datetime,(Tbl.col.value('caldate[1]', 'varchar(50)')),103) AS CalDate,`

Comment: Thanks for your help . I tried it but its still not working and 'Tbl.col.value' show 'cannot find column name or user define function "Tbl.Col.value" or aggregate Tbl.Col.value or the name is ambiguous' error.

Comment: share sample of your xml data so that i can better help

Comment: the xml you genereted is not in well format, first check and generate a well formatted xml then try

Comment: @@ Trilochan Sahu check my answer , I m sure this will resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks for ur help but following error are coming in sql server:-Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure Ecal_InsertVerniercal_Sp, Line 5
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Calibration_Date', table 'New_DB.dbo.Vernier_Gauge_Calibration'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string error are coming in sql

Comment: with out date datatype its working fine but with date its not working.

Comment: provide a screenshot of your table in which you want to insert the xml data

Comment: I have attch 2 images of my database table please help me the resolve this issue

Comment: @@Trilochan you are very new to this site so please be careful about not provide your full db or project code try to give the part of the table structure only , like open your table in design mode and then printscreen and then crop to that section only then send.

Comment: @@Trilochan the above sql i've provide just run it and then you got the values with columnname then just insert them to the table without using proc just for test then try it in your proc

Comment: Thanks for your concern but I am getting following error:Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Ecal_InsertVerniercal_Sp, Line 5
The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Comment: please check the number of column you want to insert and the sequence of columns . this error occurs when the number of column and number of value not match

Comment: @@Trilochan thik it and vote it up. don't forget to tick it

Comment: where my ans start their left side

Comment: use Up arrow and thick button left side of answer